# I can file.addToFolder but cant file.removeFromFolder

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-drive-api

I have a script that reads files from a folder and catalogs the contents to a spreadsheet. To avoid duplicates I want to move the files to a different folder (file.addToFolder(newFolder)) which works, however when I try to file.removeFromFolder(formerFolder) I get "cannot find method" which would suggest I am not giving it the right class of object even though removeFromFolder is listed as a member of the File class.

```
function moveFileToFolder(fileId, targetFolderId,formerFolderId) {
  var targetFolder = DocsList.getFolderById(targetFolderId);
  var file = DocsList.getFileById(fileId);
  file.addToFolder(targetFolder);
  file.removeFromFolder(formerFolderId);
};
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get the `formerFolder` like you get the `targetfolder` and pass it to the method instead of the `formerFolderId`.

Comment: Super! SO obvious now. Thanks a bunch Henrique, your my hero.

Comment: Haha, thanks. By the way, since you're new here. You should mark an answer as accepted when you feel you got a good one. Voting is also another nice feature we have here in StackOverflow.

Comment: Ok i acepted, but i cant vote because im so new. Im trying to answer some others questions.